# Exclude min values from Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate

I have table MyTable (Id, LocationId, UserName, Date, Rank)

I need to delete duplicates from this table, but left row with min Id

```
select min(cr.id)
from MyTable mt
group by mt.LocationId, mt.UserName, mt.Date, mt.Rank
having count(mt.id) > 1
```

This is query to select min values from group... But don't know how to exclude them from query with duplicates

```
select mt.LocationId, mt.UserName, mt.Date, mt.Rank
from MyTable mt
group by mt.LocationId, mt.UserName, mt.Date, mt.Rank
having count(mt.id) > 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER()`
The `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()` function is looking for rows with the same values of your duplicates columns. The first occurrence of this combination of columns is being allocated a `rn` of 1, the next one 2, 3 and so on.
Ordering by `Id` ascending you will have the smallest as rn = 1 so deleting `where rn > 1`, removes duplicates and keeps the row with smallest id.

```
with cte as (
    select
        *
        ,rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY LocationId, UserName, Date, Rank order by id asc)
    from MyTable 
)
delete from cte where rn > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `row_number()` function :

```
delete mt
from (select mt.*,
             row_number() over (partition by mt.LocationId, mt.UserName, mt.Date, mt.Rank order by mt.id) as seq
      from MyTable mt
     ) mt
where seq > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `row_number` window function

```
with t1 as
(
select * , 
row_number() over(partition by mt.LocationId, mt.UserName, mt.Date, mt.Rank order by Id) as rn from MyTable mt
) delete from t1 where t1.rn!=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use row_number()

```
 delete m from 
 (select mt.id, mt.LocationId, mt.UserName, mt.Date, mt.Rank,
 row_number() over(partion by mt.LocationId, mt.UserName, mt.Date, mt.Rank 
 order by mt.id) as rn
 from MyTable mt) m where rn<>1
```